# CoreData with Swift and iOS 8+ still needs willAccessValueForKey()?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm writing a function in my NSManagedObject subclass called **Friend**.

I wonder if I should write this (user is another NSManagedObject **User**):

```
  func firstCharacterOfComputerDisplayName() -> String
  {
    guard let user = self.friend else {
      return ""
    }
    return user.firstCharacterOfComputerDisplayName()
  }
```

or that:

```
  func firstCharacterOfComputerDisplayName() -> String
  {
    self.willAccessValue(forKey: "friend")

    guard let user = self.primitiveValueForKey("friend") as? User else {
      self.didAccessValue(forKey: "friend")
      return ""
    }
    let dispName = user.firstCharacterOfComputerDisplayName()
    self.didAccessValue(forKey: "friend")
    return dispName
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to use `willAccessValue(forKey:)`, `primitiveValueForKey(_:)` and `didAccessValue(forKey:)` isn't related to whether you use Swift or iOS 8. It's strictly a Core Data thing. Core Data uses KVO to maintain data graph integrity and so on, so it has certain expectations about when it will observe changes and access.

**Mostly** you don't need to care about those methods unless you are overriding an accessor method. If you want the value of `self.friend`, just ask for it as `self.friend`. Unless you're overriding the accessors for `friend`, except you're not doing that here.

Comment: I've read so many documentations and tutorials + the recent iOS talks from apple and I got confused. I guess in my specific case, the first solution does the trick here as friend is already an accessor managed by coredata.